# Do you need two separate APKs for LiveCard service and Immersions?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am writing a GDK application for work. I have the immersion application down, and under approval by Google. Of the feedback received, they strongly recommend including a Live Card service. Are they recommending I submit two separate APKs? I did not think an application on Glass could be both a Live Card service and an immersion. Am I wrong?

Comment: Immersion is in fact a specific Activity property. And LiveCard and simply a special type of Card (controlled by a Service). Both can be bundled in the same application.

Comment: You have to just use one .apk for your application, what you need to do is to integrate both Live Card and immersion together. Please follow the instructions in the link below.
https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/checklist

For tutorial this is a good example
http://www.toptal.com/google-glass/building-your-first-glass-app-a-tutorial-for-aspiring-google-glass-developers